# How can I get a symbol to behave like an infix operator?

Tags: math-operators

For example, how can I get "`x \overline{*} y`" to parse like "`x * y`"? I know I can adjust the manual spacing using "`\,`", but is there a less superficial way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$ x \mathbin{\overline{*} }y $
```